# How to insert NULL into column with type of timestamp in postgresql3

Tags: python, postgresql

Getting error when inserting null values in column of type `timestamp`.

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type `timestamp: "" CONTEXT:  COPY work3, line 1, column call_pickup_time:

I have defined default value `null` of column but still not working?

Comment: `NULL` <> empty string. It works well with `NULL`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=5f48df4d2466d52d4396a1ae65495c49 Make sure you insert `NULL` not an empty string here. And if you want the default use `DEFAULT`.

Comment: You may want to show your INSERT statement.

Comment: Null is perfectly fine for timestamp type columns. The following works perfectly
```
create table test (value_a timestamp);
insert into test(value_a) values (null);
```
Check your DDL and make sure you are really inserting `null` values and not empty strings since your error suggests otherwise.